# Ubuntu terminal not taking keyboard input while asking for user password

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using [Ubuntu](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH4MSV6) on Windows 10. I have the **Windows subsystem for Linux** flag turned on (evidenced by the following image).

[image]

Recently, I tried to change my Unix password.

[image]

At this point, the terminal is not taking any keyboard input. Then I tried from the command prompt as well as the PowerShell but no avail.

[image]

<sup>*Click on the image to enlarge it*</sup>

I want to know the reason behind this problem and how to fix it. Thank you for paying attention to my post.

Comment: Passwords aren't echoed in terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Everything is working as expected.**

The terminal isn't printing what you're typing to prevent shoulder surfing.

Type your password and confirm with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Wasn't I supposed to see dots?

Comment: No, not in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Linux terminal doesn't show the dots. It never does, you just have to type your password en press enter.

It looks like this when it works :

```
emile@emile-Aspire-E1-470P:~$ su
Password: 
root@emile-Aspire-E1-470P:/home/emile#
```

Answer (score 1):

While most Linux distros don't show dots during typing password, some distros may display asterisks (*) using sudo. This can be achievable by doing the following:

1. Access sudo config:

```
sudo visudo
```

2. Find the following line:

```
Defaults env_reset
```

3. And append `pwfeedback` next to it. Now the line should look like this:

```
Defaults env_reset, pwfeedback
```

4. Reset the terminal

```
reset
```

Source: https://www.tecmint.com/show-asterisks-sudo-password-in-linux/